# i have a mistake in my adapter class

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listview, android-toast

```
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_messages, container, false);


    brands.add("microsoft");
    brands.add("ios" );
    brands.add("android");
    AdapterListView adapter = new AdapterListView(brands,getActivity());

    ListView listView = (ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.mobile_list);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                    "selected " + i, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
        }
    });
```

when am actually toasting the i only am able to print the position,i also want to print the values in brands for the selection made .how can i so that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get list member by using `get`.

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                        "selected " + i + brands.get(i), Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
            }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Get selected item string like this:

```
String item = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
```

Where **parent** is your AdapterView and **position** is the position of the selected item which in your case are **adapterView** and **i**